# Referral from Flickr shown as direct/none in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Flickr account with some photos that have links in their description linking to my website. However, when checking in my Google Analytics account the `Source/Medium`, it appears as `direct/none`, although I would expect it to be `flickr/referral`.

I have read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/marketing/comments/5ad68v/does_traffic_from_flickr_end_up_in_directnone/) that it could be due to the ad blockers, but it is not the case since I did the test with a browser without any ad blocker extension installed.

Also, according to [this](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Referral-Spam/Google-Analytics-not-showing-referrals-from-specific-url/m-p/1154805#M1624):

> - https to https = should send referral info
> - http to http  = should send referral info
> - http to https = should send referral info
> - https to http = no wont send referral info
>
> To track https to http:
>
> If you use custom campaign tagging on the url then it should pass whatever info
>   you put into the tags as the medium/source etc.. make sure to test
>   that though
>
> Other alternatives would be to:
>
> either change the site B
>   to https too
>
> or
>
> use an internal redirection script to send visitors
>   to a http page on the https site before then passing them thru to the
>   http website

Flickr is https, my site http.

However, facebook is also https and I am getting those properly. According to [this other post](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Analytics-Academy/Referral-Source-Not-Showing-in-GA/m-p/951315#M1257):

> sites like facebook and similar are https but are setup specifically
>   on their side to allow passing of referral information

How can I make that GA shows those visits as `flickr/referral`?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is, as suggested in the second quote of the question, to use a custom campaign tagging and add the following to the link:

```
?utm_medium=social&utm_source=flickr.com&utm_campaign=photo
```

Then it will be shown properly in Google Analytics.

I found [this article](https://www.annielytics.com/guides/definitive-guide-campaign-tagging-google-analytics/) very useful to learn about Custom Campaigns.

Note that this does not work if one cannot edit the description, i.e., it will work for own content only.